# PHP - preg_replace on an array not working as expected

Tags: php

I have a PHP array that looks like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => post: 746
    [1] => post: 2
    [2] => post: 84
)
```

I am trying to remove the `post:` from each item in the array and return one that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 746
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 84
)
```

I have attempted to use preg_replace like this...

```
$array = preg_replace('/^post: *([0-9]+)/', $array );
print_r($array);
```

But this is not working for me, how should I be doing this?

Comment: [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) requires three parameters. You are using only 2. This will give syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the second argument of `preg_replace` function, which is with what should replace the match, also your regex has small problem, here is the fixed version:

```
preg_replace('/^post:\s*([0-9]+)$/', '$1', $array );
```

**Demo**: https://3v4l.org/64fO6

Comment: Thank you, that work now. What was the issue with the regex?

Comment: @fightstarr20 when catching white spaces you should use `\s` instead of space character. If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: I'm not a huge proponent of micro optimization, but it's worth pointing out that this is going to be slower than a lot of the other answers pointing you away from preg_replace for this question.  Use Regex when you need it, but you absolutely don't need it for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a pattern for the replacement, or a empty string place holder.

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject)
```

Is what you are trying to do (there are other args, but they are optional).

```
$array = preg_replace('/post: /', '', $array );
```

Should do it.

```
<?php

$array=array("post: 746",
        "post: 2",
        "post: 84");

$array = preg_replace('/^post: /', '', $array );
print_r($array);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => 746
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 84
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this that don't involve regular expressions, which are really not needed for breaking up a simple string like this.

For example:

```
<?php

$input = Array( 'post: 746', 'post: 2', 'post: 84');

$output = array_map(function ($n) {
    $o = explode(': ', $n);
    return (int)$o[1];
}, $input);

var_dump($output);
```

And here's another one that is probably even faster:

```
<?php

$input = Array( 'post: 746', 'post: 2', 'post: 84');

$output = array_map(function ($n) {
    return (int)substr($n, strpos($n, ':')+1);
}, $input);

var_dump($output);
```

If you don't need integers in the output just remove the cast to int.

Or just use str_replace, which in many cases like this is a drop in replacement for preg_replace.

```
<?php

$input = Array( 'post: 746', 'post: 2', 'post: 84');
$output = str_replace('post: ', '', $input);

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without using a regex using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to check the prefix and return the string without the prefix:

```
$items = [
    "post: 674",
    "post: 2",
    "post: 84",
];

$result = array_map(function($x){
    $prefix = "post: ";
    if (substr($x, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
        return substr($x, strlen($prefix));
    }
    return $x;
}, $items);

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 674
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 84
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()` to iterate the array then strip out any non-digital characters via `filter_var()` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` or `trim()` with a "character mask" containing the six undesired characters.

You can also let `preg_replace()` do the iterating for you.  Using `preg_replace()` offers the most brief syntax, but regular expressions are often slower than non-preg_ techniques and it may be overkill for your seemingly simple task.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3XiZH))

```
$array = ["post: 746", "post: 2", "post: 84"];

// remove all non-integer characters
var_export(array_map(function($v){return filter_var($v, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);}, $array));

// only necessary if you have elements with non-"post: " AND non-integer substrings
var_export(preg_replace('~^post: ~', '', $array));

// I shuffled the character mask to prove order doesn't matter
var_export(array_map(function($v){return trim($v, ': opst');}, $array));
```

Output: (from each technique is the same)

```
array (
  0 => '746',
  1 => '2',
  2 => '84',
)
```

p.s. If anyone is going to entertain the idea of using `explode()` to create an array of each element then store the second element of the array as the new desired string (and I wouldn't go to such trouble) be sure to:

1. split on  or `:` (colon, space) or even `post:` (post, colon, space) because splitting on `:` (colon only) forces you to tidy up the second element's leading space and
2. use `explode()`'s 3rd parameter (`limit`) and set it to `2` because logically, you don't need more than two elements